# Evaluating a polynomial, using a dynamically allocated array for coefficients, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, polynomial-math

I asked for the values of the coefficients, storing them in a dynamically allocated array, the value of the variable and the degree of the polynomial, but the value of the variable p that should contain the value of the polynomial doesn't get updated after I initialize it. I tried with the values x=3, n=3 a(n...0) = {3,3,3,3} and the return value is 3
I used Horner's method for the computation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dynamic_arr
{
    int nelem;
    double arr[1];
};
double polynomial(struct dynamic_arr *a,int n, double x);


int main()
{
    struct dynamic_arr *a;
    int n;
    double pl;
    double x = 2;
    int scancount;
    do
    {
        printf("enter the degree of the polynomial: ");
        scancount = scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    while (scancount == 0);
    a = malloc(sizeof(struct dynamic_arr)+sizeof(int)*(n+1));
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    a->nelem == n;
    do
    {
        printf("enter the coefficient of the %d degree monomial:", n);
        scancount = scanf("%lf", &a->arr[n]);
        while(getchar() != '\n')
            ;
    }
    while (scancount == 0 || n-- > 0);
    do
    {
        printf("enter x :");
        scancount = scanf("%lf", &x);
    }
    while (scancount != 1);

        pl = polynomial(a,a->nelem,x);
    printf("%f", pl);
        free(a);
    return 0;
}

double polynomial(struct dynamic_arr *a,int n, double x)
{
    double p;
    p= a->arr[2];
    while (--n >= 0)
    {
        p = p*x+a->arr[n];
    }

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a->nelem == n;
```

is a comparison with unused value, not an assignment.

---

```
p= a->arr[2];
```

should be

```
p= a->arr[n];
```

---

```
a = malloc(sizeof(struct dynamic_arr)+sizeof(int)*(n+1));
```

is not enough memory, as the array used has as data type 8byte `double`, not 4byte `int`.

Comment: the second one was actually a value that I had substituted to n during debugging.

Comment: change the data type in sizeof(int) after changing the type of the coefficients from int to double (I don't know why I can't edit my previous comment even if I sent it by mistake)

Comment: You should be able to delete your comments, so just start anew. Did you correct the first problem, replace `==` by `=`?